Cannot download package league/flysystem-path-prefixing in Laravel 11
When I using composer require league/flysystem-path-prefixing "^3.0" I get this error
Composer could not detect the root package (laravel/laravel) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See https://getcomposer.org/root-version
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-path-prefixing 3.0 (exact version match: 3.0, 3.0.0 or 3.0.0.0), found league/flysystem-path-prefixing[3.3.0, ..., 3.x-dev, 4.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
I try solving the error by using composer update, composer clear-cache and require the package again but still get this error. Can you please help me this? Thank you!

same? one thing, do you have "laravel/framework" in the require on composer.json?
